# How to show sub categories under main category

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I need some help on classic ASP.
Currently, the output shows like:

```
cat
south
cat
south
cat2
east
cat2
west
```

I don't want to see the main categories repeating like that.
How do I combine main category into one and show sub categories below main?
Like:

```
cat
south
south
cat2
east
west

Category table
ID   Category
------------
01  cat
02  cat2
03  cat3

Subcat table
ID   Subcat   Category_id
-------------------------
1   south     01
2   north     01
3   east      02
4   west      02
5   line      03
```

Code:

```
<%
sSQL =   " SELECT s.*, c.* FROM Category c, Subcat s WHERE s.Subcat_id =     c.Subcat_id "
  objRS.Open sSQL, objCon
  response.Write sSQL
  Do Until objRS.EOF
    sCategory = objRS("Category")
  sSubcat = objRS("Subcat")
%>
<input type="text" name="CategoryN" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%=   sCategory %>"><br />
<input type="text" name="SubcatN" size="40" maxlength="50" value="<%= sSubcat %>"><br />
<%
objRS.MoveNext
Loop
objRS.Close
%>
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<%
  currCat = "~~~~~~"
  sSQL = "SELECT s.*, c.* FROM Category c, Subcat s WHERE s.Subcat_id = c.Subcat_id "
  objRS.Open sSQL, objCon
  response.Write sSQL
  Do Until objRS.EOF
    sCategory = objRS("Category")
    sSubcat = objRS("Subcat")

    if currCat <> sCategory Then
       currCat = sCategory 
       <%
        <input type="text" name="CategoryN" size="40" 
         maxlength="50" value="<%=sCategory%>"><br />
       %>
    End If
    %>
      <input type="text" name="SubcatN" size="40" 
      maxlength="50" value="<%= sSubcat %>"><br />
<%
    objRS.MoveNext
  Loop

   objRS.Close
%>
```